# Error when upload a folder into mysql using spring MVC

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, jsp

I am building an application. The user will view a page, and the user should input the patient code, and following description, and than, the user will upload folder consist of CSV files.
 I am trying to upload "a folder consist of CSV files"(not zip/rar file), using spring MVC - JSP

This is my JSP code:

```
<div class="w3-row w3-section">
                        <div class="w3-col" style="width:200px">* Patient code</div>
                        <div class="w3-rest">
                            <%--<form:select path="patient">--%>
                                <%--<form:options items="${patient}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id"/>--%>
                            <%--</form:select>--%>
                                <form:input type="text" path="id_patient" name="id_patient" id="id_patient" placeholder="input number 1-20" class="w3-input w3-border"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="w3-row w3-section">
                        <div class="w3-col" style="width:200px">* Patient description</div>
                        <div class="w3-rest">
                            <form:input type="text" path="description" name="description" id="description" placeholder="put any description" class="w3-input w3-border"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="w3-row w3-section">
                        <div class="w3-col" style="width:200px">* Input Data Files</div>
                        <div class="w3-rest">
                            <input type="file" path="fileName" name="attachFileObj" webkitdirectory directory />
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

This is my Patient.java file:

```
public class Patient {

    //field patient
    private int id_patient;
    private String description;
    private String patient;


    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getId_patient() {
        return id_patient;
    }

    public void setId_patient(int id_patient) {
        this.id_patient = id_patient;
    }

    public String getPatient() {
        return patient;
    }

}
```

This is my attachment.java class:

```
package com.Patient.pojo;

public class Attachment {
    //field attachment
    private int id_data;
    private byte[] data;
    private String fileName;
    private int patientID;

    public int getId_data() {
        return id_data;
    }

    public void setId_data(int id_data) {
        this.id_data = id_data;
    }

    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getPatientID() {
        return patientID;
    }

    public void setPatientID(int patientID) {
        this.patientID = patientID;
    }
}
```

This is my dao file:

```
@Override
    public void saveAttachment(Patient patient, Attachment attachment) {

        if(null != jdbcTemplate) {
            // Performing The Sql 'Insert' Operation
            String sql = "insert into patient(id_patient, description) values(?,?);" +
                    "insert into attachment(id_data, file_data, patientID) values (?, ?, (select patientID from patient where patientID = id_patient));";


            jdbcTemplate.update(sql, patient.getDescription(), attachment.getId_data(), attachment.getData(), attachment.getPatientID());

//            int insertCount = jdbcTemplate.update(sql, patient.getData());
//            if(insertCount == 1) {
//                System.out.println("The Uploaded File Is Successfully Saved In The Database...!" + "\n");
//            } else {
//                System.out.println("Error Occured While Saving The Uploaded File In The Database... Please Check...!" + "\n");
//            }

        } else {
            System.out.print("Application Is Not Able To Bind With The Database! Please Check!");
        }

    }
```

This is my class mapper inside Dao file:

```
class PatientMapper implements RowMapper<Patient> {

    public Patient mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1) throws SQLException {
        Patient patient = new Patient();
        patient.setId_patient(rs.getInt("id_patient"));
        patient.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));

        Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
        attachment.setId_data(rs.getInt("id_data"));
        attachment.setData(rs.getBytes("file_data"));
        attachment.setPatientID(rs.getInt("patientID"));

        return patient;
    }
}
```

This is my controller to handle save file:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/AddPatient/{reqUserName}/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveAddPatient(@ModelAttribute("patient") Patient patient,
                                       Attachment attachment,
                                       @PathVariable String reqUserName,
                                       SessionStatus status,
                                       HttpServletRequest request,
                                       final @RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile[] attachFileObj)
            throws IllegalStateException, IOException {

        // Determine If There Is An File Upload. If Yes, Attach It To The Client Email
        if ((attachFileObj != null) && (attachFileObj.length > 0) && (!attachFileObj.equals("")) &&
                (patient != null)) {
            for (CommonsMultipartFile aFile : attachFileObj) {
                if(aFile.isEmpty()) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Attachment Name?= " + aFile.getOriginalFilename() + "\n");
                    if (!aFile.getOriginalFilename().equals("")) {
                        patient = new Patient();
                        patient.setDescription(patient.getDescription());

                        attachment = new Attachment();
                        attachment.setData(aFile.getBytes());
//                        patient.setFileName(aFile.getOriginalFilename());

                        // Calling The Db Method To Save The Uploaded File In The Db
                        patientService.saveAttachment(patient, attachment);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("File Is Successfully Uploaded & Saved In The Database.... Hurrey!\n");
            }
        } else {
            // Do Nothing
        }
        modelViewObj = new ModelAndView("success_Add_Patient","messageObj","Thank You! The File(s) Is Successfully Uploaded!");
        return  modelViewObj;


    }
```

When I run the code and want to add file by upload the folder, I got this error:

```
2018-07-18 15:43:47,390 [org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory]-[INFO] SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase, Hana]
2018-07-18 15:43:47,390 [org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory]-[DEBUG] Looking up default SQLErrorCodes for DataSource [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@3948e9ec]
2018-07-18 15:43:47,391 [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils]-[DEBUG] Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2018-07-18 15:43:47,391 [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource]-[DEBUG] Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://143.167.11.2:3306/db_visualisation]
2018-07-18 15:43:47,636 [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils]-[DEBUG] Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2018-07-18 15:43:47,637 [org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory]-[DEBUG] SQL error codes for 'MySQL' found
2018-07-18 15:43:47,638 [org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory]-[DEBUG] Caching SQL error codes for DataSource [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@3948e9ec]: database product name is 'MySQL'
2018-07-18 15:43:47,638 [org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator]-[DEBUG] Translating SQLException with SQL state '42000', error code '1064', message [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into attachment(id_data, file_data, patientID) values (_binary'Transition' at line 1]; SQL was [insert into patient(id_patient, description) values(?,?);insert into attachment(id_data, file_data, patientID) values (?, ?, (select patientID from patient where patientID = id_patient));] for task [PreparedStatementCallback]
2018-07-18 15:43:47,639 [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver]-[DEBUG] Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.Patient.controller.PatientController.saveAddPatient(com.Patient.pojo.Patient,com.Patient.pojo.Attachment,java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile[]) throws java.lang.IllegalStateException,java.io.IOException]: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [insert into patient(id_patient, description) values(?,?);insert into attachment(id_data, file_data, patientID) values (?, ?, (select patientID from patient where patientID = id_patient));]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into attachment(id_data, file_data, patientID) values (_binary'Transition' at line 1
2018-07-18 15:43:47,641 [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver]-[DEBUG] Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.Patient.controller.PatientController.saveAddPatient(com.Patient.pojo.Patient,com.Patient.pojo.Attachment,java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile[]) throws java.lang.IllegalStateException,java.io.IOException]: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [insert into patient(id_patient, description) values(?,?);insert into attachment(id_data, file_data, patientID) values (?, ?, (select patientID from patient where patientID = id_patient));]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into attachment(id_data, file_data, patientID) values (_binary'Transition' at line 1
2018-07-18 15:43:47,641 [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver]-[DEBUG] Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.Patient.controller.PatientController.saveAddPatient(com.Patient.pojo.Patient,com.Patient.pojo.Attachment,java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile[]) throws java.lang.IllegalStateException,java.io.IOException]: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [insert into patient(id_patient, description) values(?,?);insert into attachment(id_data, file_data, patientID) values (?, ?, (select patientID from patient where patientID = id_patient));]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into attachment(id_data, file_data, patientID) values (_binary'Transition' at line 1
2018-07-18 15:43:47,641 [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver]-[DEBUG] Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.Patient.controller.PatientController.saveAddPatient(com.Patient.pojo.Patient,com.Patient.pojo.Attachment,java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile[]) throws java.lang.IllegalStateException,java.io.IOException]: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [insert into patient(id_patient, description) values(?,?);insert into attachment(id_data, file_data, patientID) values (?, ?, (select patientID from patient where patientID = id_patient));]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into attachment(id_data, file_data, patientID) values (_binary'Transition' at line 1
2018-07-18 15:43:47,642 [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver]-[DEBUG] Resolving to view 'error' for exception of type [org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException], based on exception mapping [java.lang.Exception]
2018-07-18 15:43:47,642 [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver]-[DEBUG] Exposing Exception as model attribute 'exception'
2018-07-18 15:43:47,642 [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet]-[DEBUG] Handler execution resulted in exception - forwarding to resolved error view: ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'error'; model is {exception=org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [insert into patient(id_patient, description) values(?,?);insert into attachment(id_data, file_data, patientID) values (?, ?, (select patientID from patient where patientID = id_patient));]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into attachment(id_data, file_data, patientID) values (_binary'Transition' at line 1}
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [insert into patient(id_patient, description) values(?,?);insert into attachment(id_data, file_data, patientID) values (?, ?, (select patientID from patient where patientID = id_patient));]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into attachment(id_data, file_data, patientID) values (_binary'Transition' at line 1
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:235)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1402)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:620)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:850)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:905)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:915)
    at com.Patient.dao.PatientDaoImpl.saveAttachment(PatientDaoImpl.java:142)
    at com.Patient.service.PatientServiceImpl.saveAttachment(PatientServiceImpl.java:68)
    at com.Patient.controller.PatientController.saveAddPatient(PatientController.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into attachment(id_data, file_data, patientID) values (_binary'Transition' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:372)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2535)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1911)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2145)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2081)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2066)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$0(JdbcTemplate.java:855)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605)
    ... 43 more
2018-07-18 15:43:47,646 [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory]-[DEBUG] Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'error'
2018-07-18 15:43:47,646 [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet]-[DEBUG] Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'error'; URL [/WEB-INF/views/error.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-mvc'
2018-07-18 15:43:47,646 [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView]-[DEBUG] Added model object 'reqUserName' of type [java.lang.String] to request in view with name 'error'
2018-07-18 15:43:47,646 [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView]-[DEBUG] Added model object 'exception' of type [org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException] to request in view with name 'error'
2018-07-18 15:43:47,646 [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView]-[DEBUG] Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/views/error.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'error'
2018-07-18 15:43:47,650 [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver]-[DEBUG] Cleaning up multipart file [attachFileObj] with original filename [PA_Not_worn.csv], stored in memory
2018-07-18 15:43:47,650 [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver]-[DEBUG] Cleaning up multipart file [attachFileObj] with original filename [flipDetection.csv], stored in memory
2018-07-18 15:43:47,650 [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver]-[DEBUG] Cleaning up multipart file [attachFileObj] with original filename [EE_NotWorn.csv], stored in memory
2018-07-18 15:43:47,650 [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver]-[DEBUG] Cleaning up multipart file [attachFileObj] with original filename [PA_Shuffling.csv], stored in memory
2018-07-18 15:43:47,650 [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver]-[DEBUG] Cleaning up multipart file [attachFileObj] with original filename [EE_Moderate.csv], stored in memory
2018-07-18 15:43:47,650 [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver]-[DEBUG] Cleaning up multipart file [attachFileObj] with original filename [EE_Recommendations.csv], stored in memory
2018-07-18 15:43:47,650 [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet]-[DEBUG] Successfully completed request
```

This the table inside the database:

[image: tables inside database]

Any one can help me, how to solve this? so that I can upload the folder consist of csv files in to database mysql?

Comment: You cannot execute multiple queries at a time using jdbctemplate . If queries structure are same you can use batch operation.

Comment: do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: `String sql1 = "insert into patient(id_patient, description) values(?,?);";
String sql2 = "insert into attachment(id_data, file_data, patientID) values (?, ?, (SELECT MAX(patientID )  from patient));"
            jdbcTemplate.update(sql1, 0,patient.getDescription());
           jdbcTemplate.update(sql2, 0, attachment.getData());`Try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can run both of these at the same time:

```
if(null != jdbcTemplate) {
            // Performing The Sql 'Insert' Operation
            String sql = "insert into patient(id_patient, description) values(?,?);" +
                    "insert into attachment(id_data, file_data, patientID) values (?, ?, (select patientID from patient where patientID = id_patient));";


            jdbcTemplate.update(sql, patient.getDescription(), attachment.getId_data(), attachment.getData(), attachment.getPatientID());
```

Maybe try:

```
    if(null != jdbcTemplate) {
                // Performing The Sql 'Insert' Operation
                String sql = "insert into patient(id_patient, description) values(?,?);"; 

                String sqlTwo = "insert into attachment(id_data, file_data, patientID) values (?, ?, (select patientID from patient where patientID = id_patient));";


jdbcTemplate.update(sql, patient.getDescription(), attachment.getId_data(), attachment.getData(), attachment.getPatientID());

jdbcTemplate.update(sqlTwo, patient.getDescription(), attachment.getId_data(), attachment.getData(), attachment.getPatientID());
```

Also

You cannot bind parameters with a nested subquery:

```
values (?, ?, (select patientID from patient where patientID = id_patient))
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. Before I tried your code, you said "You cannot bind parameters with a nested subquery: ... ( `values (?, ?, (select patientID from patient where patientID = id_patient))`)" So, How should I change that part?

Comment: Hi, I have tried your code, but I got this error: `2018-07-18 16:25:54,478 
2018-07-18 16:25:54,479 [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver]-[DEBUG] Resolving exception from handler `

Comment: `[public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.Patient.controller.PatientController.saveAddPatient(com.Patient.pojo.Patient,com.Patient.pojo.Attachment,java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFil`

Comment: `e[]) throws java.lang.IllegalStateException,java.io.IOException]: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [insert into attachment(id_data, file_data, patientID) select ?,?,patientID from patient where patientID = ?]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'patientID' in 'field list'`

Comment: Yeah. This looks to be cause by binding on the subquery. You need to set a variable first using that sql statement and then pass it into the query using ?, like you are the others.

Comment: Hi, I have solve it, and it successful inserted. The data insert from the folder is 36 files But when I saw the attachment table it empty. But the patient consist of more then 36 id.

Comment: Well, at least seems like you have solved your original issue.  Now on to the next one....As it goes.

Comment: If this answered helped solve your problem, can you mark as answered please?

Answer (score 1):

You insert sql have many places need to change:

a. You can use only `SELECT` when you use `INSERT INTO`,also in this case you need to remove keyword `VALUES`

b. need to remove `;` at the end of the sql

c.You can not execute two `INSERT INTO` within one sql

so change

```
  String sql = "insert into patient(id_patient, description) values(?,?);" 
           + "insert into attachment(id_data, file_data, patientID) values (?, ?, (select patientID from patient where patientID = id_patient));";
```

to two separate sql

```
  String sqlA = "insert into patient(id_patient, description) values(?,?)";
  String sqlB = "insert into attachment(id_data, file_data, patientID) 
      values(?,?,?);
```

in this case,you need to invoke `jdbcTemplate.update()` twice for each sql

Comment: Thank you for the respond, I have tried your code, but between the `values` and `select` there is the red line, I think it need "()"? but when I tried to cover the select query with the symbol it getting error

Comment: @AgnesPalit just updated my answer,you can check again

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I have tried. And I got this error `2018-07-18 16:15:17,074 [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet]-[DEBUG] Handler execution resulted in exception -

Comment: @AgnesPalit What do you mean by red line,can you show us the detailed error message?

Comment: forwarding to resolved error view: ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'error'; model is {exception=org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [insert into attachment(id_data, file_data, patientID) select ?,?,patientID from patient where patientID = id_patientParameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2).; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2).}`

Comment: Sorry for the "red line" I have tried you lastest update code and there is no redline. But I got the error above

Comment: @AgnesPalit the error message is clear,the parameter number is incorrect,you need to check you code,also I updated my answer again for `sqlB`,now you need pass 3 parameters to `sqlB`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176261/discussion-between-agnes-palit-and-lucumt).